# How to connect a certificate for mail access gmail.com in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I'm reviewing a training project - working with a mail server gmail.com. An error occurred at startup:

```
Failed receive: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

On this site I found instructions on how to connect the certificate: [PKIX path building failed” and “unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)
I'm reviewing a training project - working with a mail server gmail.com. An error occurred at startup:

Failed receive: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
On this site I found instructions on how to connect the certificate: PKIX path building failed” and " unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I did everything according to the instructions:

1. In chrome, I downloaded the certificate from this site, saved it to the mg mail.cer file
2. I connected it with the command

   keytool -import -alias gmail -keystore c:\Development\Java\jdk11\lib\security\cacerts -file m gmail.com
3. I overloaded the computer, but the error still remains
4. I check with the command

   keytool -list -trustcacerts -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
   the certificate is in the list:

   mgmail, 2 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
   Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 9A:63:32:BE:95:...

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

According to this error, It seems like you haven't imported the [full cert chai](https://shagihan.medium.com/what-is-certificate-chain-and-how-to-verify-them-be429a030887)n to the trust store (root, intermediate and leaf certs).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjL5u.png)

In Firefox, You can easily download the full certificate chain. Then please import all 3 certificates to your trust store.

Comment: Downloaded the entire certificate chain. I connected them. It's still the same mistake. I don't understand what else needs to be done?

Comment: Thing is if you import certificate chain to the trust store, It will only import the first certificate of the chain. instead, Please download 3 certificates separately and import them one at a time to the keystore. Then you might have to restart your application to get this change effect, And also, Please verify whether the certificate was successfully imported using the "keytool -list" command

Comment: I don't understand how you can download a certificate chain with different files. I go to the certificates page in FireFox. And there you can download either a certificate or a chain of certificates in one file.

Comment: I copied three certificates from the google site. They had the same names, but different sizes. I connected all three certificates. It's still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure while importing the cerficate specifying the alias matters,
i tried below and its working for me.

1).
Use git bash command line tool(if you are in windows)
$ **echo | openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > yourcert.pem**

2).
Now copy the certificate to JDK\bin directory or specify the location of your certificate file and execute the below command in Administrator mode.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin>keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\lib\security\cacerts" -file yourcert.pem